# Подключение библиотеки JavaMail Android Studio

Tags: java, android, библиотеки

Подключил jar-ники библиотеки JavaMail в андройд студии,[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И получил вот такую гадость,как поправить товарищи?

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! текстовую информацию лучше предоставлять в виде текста, а не картинки: и читать удобнее, и поисковики её проиндексируют

Answer (score 2):

Обновите Gradle либо попробуйте ответ [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673888/duplicate-files-copied-android-studio-0-4-0)

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}
```